# how to make python2.7 main python (alongside python 2.6) without breaking yum in centos?

Tags: centos, python, yum

I was told that yum is dependent on python 2.6 so i cannot remove 2.6 but i need python 2.7 to run my django project on my centOS server. Any workaround is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for such tasks. Basically it allows to install multiple Python versions in your home dir, so that system Python is not affected and you can switch between versions.